# nth term derivative with f(0) plugged in

Tags: calculus, analysis

Question: compute the sixth derivative of $\frac{\cos{(5x^2)}-1}{x^2}$ and plug in zero to the derivative. What is the answer?

I keep concluding that this question should be 892857 when I plug in 0 into the sixth derivative. Yet this comes up as wrong when plugged into this online grader. Any help as to why it isn't 892857 and why it would be something else?

If you get 892857 as your answer also, please let me know. Looking for some support either in knowing that I am right, or in that knowing I calculated this wrong.

Comment: Won't the answer be undefined as you will have `x` terms in the denominator?

Comment: I've plugged in undefined, 0 , and impossible and all three answers also yield an incorrect, showing that the gradebot wants an integer value... Super confused by this question.

Comment: I don't think there can be an integer value. I think it is a typo in the problem statement

Comment: 1) As user2612743 points out, the function is undefined at $x=0$ so all derivatives will also be undefined at zero. Do you mean find the limit of the sixth derivative? 2) What method did you use? An easy way is to expand cosine into its McLaurin series, find the McLaurin series of your function, take its sixth derivative and set x to zero. (This effectively finds the limit of the 6th derivative.)

Comment: No @RoryDaulton, didn't mean the limit of the sixth derivative. I understand that logically, it should be undefined because everything multiplies by something like 1/x^8 which would be 1/0 but, other students had a variation of this problem and got integer answers by ignoring the 1/x^8 term so I am trying to figure out a logical integer I could plug in...It is pretty confusing

Comment: Have you learned any Taylor series? If so, then the series expansion of $\cos x$ is the simplest approach. Otherwise, try using the chain rule with $u=5x^2$. (And no, 892857 isn't the answer.)

Comment: @user3819671 I would assume the grader wants the limit.  (As that *is* an integral value)

Comment: How would I go about solving the limit of the undefined derivative?

Answer (score 2):

**Outline:** Expand $\cos(5x^2)$ in a power series, using the familiar Maclaurin series expansion of $\cos(t)$. We get that the first few terms are
$$1-5^2x^4/2+5^4x^8/4!- 5^6 x^{12}/6!+\cdots.$$

Subtract $1$, divide term by term by $x^2$. The coefficient of $x^6$ is $5^4/4!$. Now note that in general the coefficient of $x^n$ in the MacLaurin expansion of a function $f(x)$ is $\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$.

Comment: But when taking the derivatives directly and evaluating at 0 the result in undefined. The limit of the 6th derivative as x->0 gives the above answer however. Why the discrepancy?

Comment: The function is technically undefined at $x=0$. But it has a **removable singularity** there, if we define it to be $-25/2$ at $x=0$, the resulting function will be infinitely differentiable. Informally, removable singularities don't count, respectable pieces of software mostly don't even bother to notice.

Comment: Using the coefficient 5^4/4! still gets me an incorrect answer. I approached this problem using a Maclaurin series expansion also. Would I need to divide the 5^4/4! by anything?

Comment: The answer  is not $5^4/4!$. This is the sixth derivative at $0$ divided by $6!$, so the sixth derivative is $(5^4 /4!)(6!)$.

Comment: Thank you Andre! This problem has been a hassle for the last 3 hours of my peers and my day. I'll be consulting a professor about it tomorrow but appreciate your help today.